# Type interface com.example.JSF.mappings.StudentMapper is not known to the MapperRegistry

Tags: java, mybatis

I am trying to get data from database using mybatis 3.2 and when I run the project this error appearing :
**Type interface com.example.JSF.mappings.StudentMapper is not known to the MapperRegistry.**

**StudentMapper**

```
package com.example.JSF.mappings;

import com.example.JSF.bean.Student;

import java.util.List;


public interface StudentMapper {

    List<Student> findAllStudents();
    Student findStudentById(Integer id);
    void insertStudent(Student student);


}
```

**MyBatis file config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
<typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="Student"
               type="com.example.JSF.bean.Student"/>
</typeAliases>
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsf"/>
            <property name="username" value="root"/>
            <property name="password" value=""/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="StudentMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
</configuration>
```

**StudentMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.JSF.bean.Student">
    <resultMap type="Student" id="StudentResult">
      <id property="studId" column="stud_id"/>
      <result property="name" column="name"/>
      <result property="email" column="email"/>
       <result property="dob" column="dob"/>
    </resultMap>
<select id="findAllStudents" resultMap="StudentResult">
    SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
</select>
<select id="findStudentById" parameterType="int"
        resultType="Student">
    SELECT STUD_ID AS STUDID, NAME, EMAIL, DOB
    FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUD_ID=#{Id}
</select>
  <insert id="insertStudent" parameterType="Student">
      INSERT INTO STUDENTS(STUD_ID,NAME,EMAIL,DOB)
      VALUES(#{studId },#{name},#{email},#{dob})
  </insert>
</mapper>
```

**MyBatisSqlSessionFactory**

```
package com.example.JSF.bean;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.*;
public class MyBatisSqlSessionFactory
{
   private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;
   public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    if(sqlSessionFactory==null) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = Resources.
                    getResourceAsStream("mybatis-config.xml");
            sqlSessionFactory = new
                    SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
        }
    }
    return sqlSessionFactory;
}
  public static SqlSession openSession() {
      return getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
  }
}
```

**StudentService**

```
package com.example.JSF.service;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.JSF.bean.MyBatisSqlSessionFactory;
import com.example.JSF.bean.Student;
import com.example.JSF.mappings.StudentMapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class StudentService {
    private final Logger logger =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

public List<Student> findAllStudents() {
    SqlSession sqlSession =
            MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        StudentMapper studentMapper =
                sqlSession.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);
        return studentMapper.findAllStudents();
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();
    }
}

public Student findStudentById(Integer studId) {
    logger.debug("Select Student By ID :{}", studId);
    SqlSession sqlSession =
            MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        StudentMapper studentMapper =
                sqlSession.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);
        return studentMapper.findStudentById(studId);
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();
    }
}


public void createStudent(Student student) {
    SqlSession sqlSession =
            MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        StudentMapper studentMapper =
                sqlSession.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);
        studentMapper.insertStudent(student);
        sqlSession.commit();
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you end up here this is how to solve it:
Actually I made a mistake in StudentMapper.xml
Instead of refer to `Model`

```
 <mapper namespace="com.example.JSF.bean.Student">
```

I should refer to Interface mapper which is here `StudentMapper` like this:

```
<mapper namespace="com.example.JSF.mappings.StudentMapper">
```